# padding styles with different breakpoints not working with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 4.0 there are padding and margins styles. But neither style works for the different breakpoints and no other style is overriding the padding. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong please.

CSS

```
   .p-sm-4 {padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem !important;}
   .p-md-4 {padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem !important;}
```

My html is:

```
<li class="menu-search p-sm-4 p-md-4">
       <input placeholder="Search" class="menu-search form-control round" type="text">
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you you used media queries?

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
 .p-md-4 {padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem !important;}
}
   /* Small Devices, Tablets */
   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .p-sm-4 {padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem !important;}
}
```